# Group Value Count By Column with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm not really sure how to ask this, so I apologize if this is a repeat question. I have this data frame that looks something like this:

`| ID | Attend_x | Attend_y | Attend_z |
 | 1  |    No    |    No    |    No    |
 | 2  |    No    |    No    |   Yes    |
 | 3  |    No    |   Yes    |    No    |
 | 4  |    No    |   Yes    |   Yes    |`

I've been trying to figure out the right combination of group_by and count to get it to look like this:

`|        |   Yes    |    No    |
 |Attend_x|    0     |    4     |
 |Attend_y|    2     |    2     |
 |Attend_z|    2     |    2     |`

I'm honestly stumped. So any advice is super appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way from `value_counts`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).T
Out[184]: 
           No  Yes
Attend_x  4.0  0.0
Attend_y  2.0  2.0
Attend_z  2.0  2.0
```

Or using `crosstab` after `melt`

```
m = df.iloc[:,1:].melt()
pd.crosstab(m.variable, m.value)

value     No  Yes
variable         
Attend_x   4    0
Attend_y   2    2
Attend_z   2    2
```